Next.js Server action secretly returns promise instead of string
I upgraded my Next js version to 14.1.4, and in a client component call checkoutWithStripe.
The actual type returned by getURL is not a String, but a Promise of some sort. I'm not sure why this happened. It used to return a string in 14.1.0.
"use server";
export const getURL = (path: string = "") => {
  const url =
    process.env.NODE_ENV == "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000/"
      : "https://ubenai.com/";

  url = url.replace(/\/+$/, "");
  path = path.replace(/^\/+/, "");

  return path ? `${url}/${path}` : url;
};

export async function checkoutWithStripe() {
  ...
  const url = getURL();
  console.log(url);
}

Current vs. Expected behavior
The following is printed:
Promise {
    'http://localhost:3000/',
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 771646,
    [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 771307,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: {
      headers: [Getter],
      cookies: [Getter],
      mutableCookies: [Getter],
      draftMode: [Getter]
    },
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: {
      isStaticGeneration: false,
      urlPathname: '/begin-trial',
      pagePath: '/(non_hero)/begin-trial/page',
      incrementalCache: [IncrementalCache],
      isRevalidate: false,
      isPrerendering: undefined,
      fetchCache: 'default-no-store',
      isOnDemandRevalidate: false,
      isDraftMode: false,
      postpone: undefined,
      fetchMetrics: [Array],
      revalidate: 0,
      tags: [Array],
      nextFetchId: 3
    },
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: { isAction: true },
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined
  }

What I would expect:
http://localhost:3000/


Turns out every function in a "use server" file becomes a promise, even if you call it from the server environment. Solution: just move that function outside the "use server" directive scope.

Amazing! I was having an issue with a very simple and apparently synchronous function being applied to an object was returning a promise. After a day of increasingly complex rabbit holes, I saw this answer, shifted the function to a separate file and problem solved!

Your checkoutWithStripe function is marked async.

In JavaScript, Async functions always return a promise. If the return
value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be
implicitly wrapped in a promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description

It is the getURL function that is returning a promise, even though it is not marked async.

Are you calling checkoutWithStripe or getUrl? Try calling getUrl directly and see if it makes a difference. If you are calling checkoutWithStripe, just try removing async.
